# Property of Normalizer of a particular subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

I'm trying to prove the following:

Let $G$ a finite group, $H$ a subgroup of $G$ such that $|H|$ and $|G/H|$ have gcd=1. Prove that $K=N_G(K)$ for every subgroup $K$ of $G$ such that $N_G(H)\subseteq K$.

**My attempt**

I thought to use the following proposition:

**Proposition** *Let $P$ be a $p$-sylow subgroup of a finite group $G$. Then $H=N_G(H)$,  for every subgroup $H$ of $G$ such that $N_G(P)\subseteq H$.*

**Proof**. Of course $P\subseteq N_G(P)\subseteq H$, so $P$ is a $p$-sylow subgroup of $H$. Now $H\subseteq N_G(H)$ is always true. For the converse, let $x\in N_G(H)$. Now $xPx^{-1}\subseteq xHx^{-1}=H$, so $xPx^{-1}=P^x$ is again a $p$-sylow subgroup of $H$. But every $p$-sylow subgroups are conjugate, so there is $g\in H$ such that $P=P^{xg}$. But, this means $xg\in N_G(P)\subseteq H$. So
$$
x=xgg^{-1}\in H.
$$
This proves that $N_G(H)\subseteq H$. Q.E.D.

Of course, I suppose $H\ne\{1\}$ and $H\ne G$, in both case the claim is trivial.

Now, because $|H|$ and $|G/H|$ have gcd=1, there is a prime $p$ such that $p$ divides $|H|$ and not $|G/H|$. But this means that $H$ contains a $p$-sylow subgroup of $G$. Now, I thought to use the proposition, but in order to do that i need $N_G(P)$ to be contained in $K$ (for every $K$ containing $N_G(H)$), and I can't see a way to prove this. So, either this is the right path and I'm missing a minor detail in order to prove that $N_G(P)\subseteq K$, or I should consider a totally different approch.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If $G$ is solvable then this follows from Hall's generalization of Sylow's Theorem (because $H$ is a Hall subgroup of $G$). But I don't believe it is true in general - why do you think it is true?

Comment: Well I suspected this may not be true, but this is problem is listed in a textbook. So should I look for a counterexample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in my comment, this is true for finite solvable groups by P. Hall's generalization of Sylow's Theorem. Here $H$ is a Hall $\pi$-subgroup of $G$, and in solvable groups all Hall $\pi$-subgroups are conjugate, so the same argument works as in the proposition about Sylow subgroups.

For non-solvable groups, it is not true in general. It is not hard to find examples of groups having two non conjugate Hall $\pi$-subgroups. For example, ${\rm PSL}(2,7)$ has two conjugacy classes of subgroups isomorphic to $S_4$ that have index $7$.

I tried taking $G$ to be the wreath product of ${\rm PSL}(2,7)$ with a cyclic group of order $5$. Then there are subgroups $H \cong S_4^5$ with $N_G(H) \le K$, where $K$ is the base group of the wreath product. So $|H| = 24^5$ with $|G:H| = 5.7^5$, so $H$ is a Hall $\{2,3\}$-subgroup of $G$, but $N_G(K) = G \ne K$.